# Using custom font in adobe native extension for iOS

Tags: ios, adobe, native

I'm building a native extension for iOS. I'd like to use a custom font. So far, I have:

In the ANE build structure:

- the .ttf files in the same folder as the lib

In the AS lib:

- included the files in the application descriptor like this:

  UIDeviceFamily</key>
                          
                              1</string>
                              2</string>
                          </array>
                          UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                          UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
                          UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                          YES</string>
                              UIAppFonts</key>
                              
                              myFont-bold.ttf</string>
                              myFont-halb.ttf</string>
                              myFont-reg.ttf</string>
                          </array>
                          ]]>
  high

In the iOS project:

- added the files under supporting files
- added the files to compile sources in the targets build phase
- used the font in the lib like this:

  [descriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont-halb" size:11]];

Still, using the ANE (which works fine in all other regards), it defaults back to the system font. Can anybody see, what I'm missing?

Any hints appreciated!
Thanx, Marcus

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  The second step that you wrote in the iOS project section: "added the files to compile sources in the targets build phase" is unnecessary and adds a warning.  Also worth mentioning that to get the exact font name string, you can open the font in Mac's Font Book and click Cmd-I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: font-files need to be added to the app's bin-folder, too. Another pitfall: filename and fontname differ, be sure to use the right one's, where needed.